# Fast, simple data storage with a JSON API

Tags: json, data-storage

I need to store a small and simple dataset online that is retrievable as JSON. I'm thinking of something along the lines of Google Spreadsheets, had that service not been a bit unreliable from time to time.

I'm building a small web app that will display some numbers. Rather than hardcoding the numbers into the application, I need to go through the whole deployment process beforehand. When I get my hands on the numbers, I just want to pop them into the data storage service and have them available via a JSON API within a few minutes.

What is the easiest, simplest and cheapest (but reliable) way to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you write a simple php script (or other server-side language)? I mean, you can create easily an infinte expandable table, and save it into a file via server side language.

Comment: My current working environment is not built to be able to have new data served as fast as I need it to be. Therefore, I'm looking for a third party solution.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at :

- couch: http://couchdb.apache.org/
- mongodb: http://www.mongodb.org/

Answer (score 0):

When you are hosting the small web app yourself anyway, you might just static serve the JSON document with the required parameters for your app and FTP it without a whole new deployment when update is needed.

But when you have less control about the deployment, then the cheapest but least elegant way might be a shared (read-only) text file in Dropbox or similar. But check about throttling and limits and TOS first before using such a way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest and simplest is https://parse.com/ , there is a very easy to use jquery api for this storage: https://github.com/srhyne/jQuery-Parse

An example on how to put a new data into the storage:

```
$.parse.post('mykey',{ value : 'myvalue' }, function(json){console.log(json);});
```

An example on how to get this data from the storage:

```
$.parse.post('mykey', function(json){console.log(json);});
```